# Tkinter Widget color does not change

Tags: python, tkinter

When I put a widget inside the frame, the color of the frame vanishes. If it was 'black' before, then after putting a `widget(label)` inside the frame, the color again becomes white.
Here's my code:

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()
root.geometry("700x600")
f = Frame(root, height = 400, width = 400, bg = 'black')
f.pack()
id = Label(f, text = "Email:", fg = 'blue', font = ('Kristen ITC', 18))
id.pack()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `Frame` is resizing itself to the `Label`.  You need to set...:

```
...
f.pack_propagate(False)
f.pack()
...
```

In order for the `Frame` to maintain its own dimension without affected by the its children widgets.

Comment: thank you , it worked, and allowed me to learn a new concept .

Answer (score 3):

By default, widgets shrink or expand to fit their contents. When you add the button, the frame shrinks down to fit.

It appears you want the frame to take up just a part of the root window. Instead of explicitly giving the frame a width and height, it's usually better to let tkinter do that for you. Fill the frame with whatever widgets you want, and let tkinter decide how big the frame should be. Then, use appropriate options for `grid` or `pack` to arrange them logically. When tkinter is allowed to make widgets the right size, you'll end up with a much more responsive UI.

For example, if you set the `fill` and `expand` options when you call `pack` on the frame, it will not shrink to fit. If you later need to add more widgets, you won't have to modify other parts of your code to make them fit.

```
f.pack(fill="both", expad=True)
```

You can also turn off this "shrink to fit" feature by calling `f.pack_propagate(False)`, but that is rarely the right solution because it forces  you to calculate sizes, and your calculations may be wrong if you run the program on a system with different fonts or different resolutions.

Comment: "It appears you're wanting the frame to fill the whole window" I'm not too sure, he did have two explicitly different dimensions set for the `root` and the `Frame`.  Though I do agree `.pack_propagate(False)` is not necessarily the right solution until what is the end result OP is trying to achieve.  Perhaps there are multiple `Frame`s involved in different position, which means `.pack()` might not be the geometry manager of choice here.

Comment: @Idlehands: good point about the different explicit sizes of the frame and root window.